# In Unity editor, how to import package from github?

Tags: unity, unity-ui, version-control

In the latest Unity editor 2021.3.25f1 LTS, I'm trying to directly import the following package from github:

https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeFilePicker/releases/tag/v1.3.0

But when I import directly in package manager (add package from git URL), I always got the following eror:

```
[Package Manager Window] Cannot perform upm operation: Unable to add package [https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeFilePicker/releases/download/v1.3.0/NativeFilePicker.unitypackage]:
  Package name 'https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeFilePicker/releases/download/v1.3.0/NativeFilePicker.unitypackage' is invalid. [InvalidParameter].
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:356)

[Package Manager Window] Error adding package: https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeFilePicker/releases/download/v1.3.0/NativeFilePicker.unitypackage.
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:356)
```

No further information is given, clearly the name resolving is faulty. The name should be `UnityNativeFilePicker`, is it a unity bug? What can be done to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't used the correct URL. As described in the repository's README, the correct URL is https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeFilePicker.git

The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-git.html#syntax) shows that the URL should be to the `.git` page, not to the Releases page.